# Username and Password validation with user input

Tags: python, loops, authentication

Im very new to python and I am creating a user login system, I am currently on a bit of creating a username and password with user input that must meet some conditions e.g

username:

- Cannot contain any spaces
- Must be at least 5 characters
- Cannot include special characters

Your system must display a message to the user telling them what they did wrong if they did not meet
one or more of these criteria (so you will need at least 4 error messages).

My code is as below, but surely theress a better way to do this?

```python
while True:
    sNewUser1 = input("""Please enter a new username.
The username must NOT contain any spaces, it must have at least 5 characters and
it cannot include any special characters: \n\n""")

    if len(sNewUser1) < 5:
        print("Your username is too short, please enter 5 or more characters! Please try again!\n")

    elif sNewUser1.count(" ") > 0:
        print("Your username contains one or more spaces, this is not allowed! Please try again! \n")

    elif sNewUser1.isalnum() == False:
        print("Your username contains a special character please try again! \n")

    else:
        greetuser()
        break

while True:
    sNewPass1 = input("""\n\nPlease enter a new password.
It must contain:
At least one Capital letter
At least one lower case letter
At least one special character
It has to be at least 6 characters in length:\n\n""")

    if len(sNewPass1) < 6:
        print("Your username is too short, please enter 5 or more characters! Please try again!\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Answer (score 0):

- Input prompts can be shortened and more direct.
- The whole code should be wrapped in a `main()` function which is called at the end using the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition. This is a convention.
- Use `is` with boolean values, in those conditional statements.
- Use the `snake_case` naming style.
- The long strings can be broken into multiple smaller ones.
- By now, linters and code-formatters (even Pylint) will not complain about anything.

Your complete code may look something like this, although there is still room for improvement:

```
"""This is a program for validating usernames and passwords"""


def main():
    """This is the main function"""
    while True:
        new_user_1 = input("\nPlease enter a new username. "
                           "It should be at least 5 characters long "
                           "and not contain spaces or special characters: ")

        if len(new_user_1) < 5:
            print("Your username is too short. Please try again: ")
        elif new_user_1.count(" ") > 0:
            print("Your username contains spaces. Please try again: ")
        elif new_user_1.isalnum() is False:
            print("Your username contains a special character. "
                  "Please try again: ")
        else:
            # call another function
            break

    while True:
        new_pass_1 = input("\nPlease enter a new password. "
                           "It should be 6 characters long "
                           "with atleast one uppercase letter, "
                           "one lowercase letter, and one special character: ")
        if len(new_pass_1) < 6:
            print("\nYour password is too short. Please try again: ")
        elif any(lower.islower() for lower in new_pass_1) is False:
            print("\nYour password does not contain lowercase letters. "
                  "Please try again: ")
        elif any(upper.isupper() for upper in new_pass_1) is False:
            print("\nYour password does not contain uppercase letters. "
                  "Please try again: ")
        elif any(digit.isdigit() for digit in new_pass_1) is False:
            print("\nYour password does not contain digits. "
                  "Please try again: ")
        elif any(not char.isalnum() for char in new_pass_1) is False:
            print("\nYour password does not contain special characters. "
                  "Please try again: ")
        elif new_pass_1.replace(" ", "") != new_pass_1:
            print("\nYour password contains whitespaces. "
                  "Please try again: ")
        else:
            # call another function
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: The previous answer had some bugs. The new one works as intended:

- Strings were broken down into smaller ones, but spaces in the end were ommitted.
- Simple `for` loops were used, which checked whether the **whole** string was uppercase, lowercase, digits, special characters or not, instead of checking each character in the string. The new code fixes this with the use of a built-in function called [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any). From Python's official documentation:

> any(iterable):
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

Here is an explanation of why/how this works:

- `elif any(lower.islower() for lower in new_pass_1)` means: `for` **`any`** `lower` in `new_pass_1`, `if` `lower.islower()` returns `True`, then: *code goes here*. Therefore, it returns `True` if **`any`** character in the string is lowercase. So if it returns `False`, it would mean that it did not find **`any`** lowercase character in the whole string. The same applies to the checks for uppercase letters and digits.
- `elif any(not char.isalnum() for char in new_pass_1)` means: `for` **`any`** `char` in `new_pass_1`, `if` `char.isalnum()` does `not` return `True` (i.e. the char is a special character), then: *code goes here*. Therefore, it returns `True` if **`any`** character in the string is a special character (i.e not an uppercase letter, lowercase letter or digit). So if it returns `False`, it would mean that it did not find **`any`** special character in the whole string.
- If you're confused about `not char.isalnum()`: `any_string.isalnum()` checks whether `any_string` is alphanumeric or not, i.e whether it is made up of alphabets and numbers only. So inverting it with `not char.isalnum()` would now check whether `any_string` is `not` alphanumeric. And we know that if something is not alphanumeric, it is a special character. Note that this will consider whitespaces to be special characters as well, so I've added a final `if` statement to check for whitespaces.

Comment: Hi I have changed the code a bit as when I run above what you suggested it asks for the password to be either all lower or all upper or all special etc.. is there a way to just check if it has only ONE of them? I tried this..

Comment: elif ascii_lowercase in new_pass_1 < 1:
            print("Your password does not contain a lowercase letter."

Comment: @gabber_goblin123, the answer has been updated accordindly and you can test it by using the following passwords one by one and verify that each condition works as intended:

1) pass
2) password
3) Password
4) Password123
5) Password123!
6) Password123 !